# How to cast String with decimal(a.bc) to int(abc) in Java

Tags: java

I want to do some calculation with a list of `String`:

```
1.23

4.56

7.89
```

For accuracy, I want the convert the above `String` to `int`:

```
123

456

789
```

How to do that?

Sorry for my vague description. What I really need is no matter what the input is, the int value should hold the specific decimal:

Let say I need 4 decimal:

String:1 ;     int: 10000

String:1.23   int: 12300

String:1.2345 int:12345

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
long n = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(text) * 100);
```

This will mean numbers like `0.1` will be `10` not `1` and `1.110` will be `111` not `1110`

```
Let say I need 4 decimal:

String:1 ; int: 10000

String:1.23 int: 12300

String:1.2345 int:12345
```

needs

```
long n = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(text) * 10000);
```

Comment: I saw your presentation about HFT system in Java before, it's very helpful. This is what I need but I have a little concern: what's the performance of Math.round(Double.parseDouble(text) * 100);？

Comment: @user838204 It's the best option you have.  Parsing from text is relatively expensive as is creating a String object.  However you should be able to do this in well under a micro-second.

Comment: thanks for the supplements. I have another urgent questions about the quickfix ,would you please help to take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004162/weird-behavior-of-quickfix-j-after-sent-test-request-test-happens

Answer (score 6):

I would strip out the dots then parse as an int:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(str.replace(".", ""));
```

If you need there to always be 3 digits, this approach gets ugly, but doable:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt((str.replace(".", "") + "00").replaceAll("^(...).*", "$1"));
```

This avoids the vagaries of the imprecision of double values, which could lead to incorrect results due to truncation when casting from double to int.

---

Here's an example of imprecision problems:

```
int i = (int) (100 * Double.parseDouble("1.13")); // 112
```

This is because:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("1.13"); // 112.99999999999999
```

Comment: @zavior no. I'm (deliberately) using `replace()` which uses plain text search term, not `replaceAll()` which uses regex.

Comment: Except it will convert 1.1 to 11

Comment: @PeterLawrey it's supposed to as I read the question. Admittedly, it is unclear if the final scale should always be 3 digits or if it should just match the input. I have assumed the simplest interpretation

Comment: @Bohemian In that case, with 15 digits of precision, double isn't going to have precision errors.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Unfortunately, you are mistaken: `int i = (int)(100 * Double.parseDouble("1.13")); // 112`

Comment: @Bohemian Every programming should know how to round floating point numbers. ;) See my answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey sure, but it can be a trap. if you blast the dots it's just simpler code and less==good :) Oh and congrats 200K!

Comment: @Bohemian true if you want ".1.2.3.4." to parse, this is solution you want but I have found hacking numbers as text is more likely to case problems.

Comment: @Bohemian If I have 1.23 and your method can convert it to 123 but what if 1.2 and 120 is what I want? Seems your method doesn't help in this case

Comment: It's a pity you didn't give that as an example when asking. I've added a solution, but I'd go to Peter's answer if you need always 3 digits.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Aggghh! You're right! See recent comment by OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace all dots with empty strings (`text.replace(".", "")`) and then use `Integer.parseInt(text)`.

Answer (score 1):

For one `String`, you can do:

```
private static final BigDecimal ONE_HUNDRED
    = new BigDecimal(100);

// In code:
new BigDecimal(inputString).multiply(ONE_HUNDRED).intValueExact();
```

Note the use of `BigDecimal` here; a `double` will NOT do.

Note also that it will work only if the input has at most two decimal digits: if more than that, `.intValueExact()` will throw an exception (it will also throw an exception if the decimal integer is out of bounds for an `int`).

Now, it depends on how precise you need to be; this method guarantees the results. The method to remove dots and parse as `int` is obviously faster ;)

Comment: You could just use the `BigDecimal` itself rather than turning it into an `int` - this would obviously allow for arithmetic with arbitrary decimal numbers.

Comment: Well, since the OP seems to want an int... But obviously yes, you can go `BigDecimal` all the way as well.

Comment: yup - but it's often the case the the OP doesn't know what they want. For example they might have read an ancient blog post about not using `double` for arithmetic with money and to multiply things up and use an `int`...

Comment: We agree on that one ;)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use string.replace and replace all "." with "". Then you can use Integer.parseInt(str) and you will have the result.

```
str = str.replace(".", "");
int val = Integer.parseInt(str);
```